# Google Content API for Shopping: Error Creating Shipment

Tags: php, google-api, google-shopping-api

I'm looking to mark an order in Google Shopping as shipped but getting hung up with how to format the `lineItems`.  I'm following the official docs for shipping line items:

https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2.1/orders/shiplineitems

And here is my code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$service = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent($client);

// Get Order and Line Items
$order = $service->orders->get('MERCHANT-ID', 'ORDER-ID', array());
$lineItems = $order->getLineItems();

// Prepare Item Info
foreach($lineItems as $item) {
  $items = array('lineItemId' => $item->getId(),'productId' => $item->getProduct()->getId(), 'quantity' => $item->quantityPending);
}

// Prepare Shipment Info
$shipment = array('shipmentId' => 'xxx', 'carrier' => 'ups', 'trackingId' => '1234567890');

// Prepare PostBody
$postBody = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_OrdersShipLineItemsRequest();
$postBody->operationId = rand();
$postBody->lineItems = $items;
$postBody->shipmentInfos = $shipment;

// Mark Google Order as Shipped
$service->orders->shiplineitems('MERCHANT-ID', 'ORDER-ID', $postBody, array());
```

This produces the following error, but I haven't been able to figured out exactly what is wrong:

> Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Invalid value for lineItems: {lineItemId=HI2PTRMVLNCZEXP, productId=online:en:US:d3k3245, quantity=2}", "locationType": "other", "location": "" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Invalid value for lineItems: {lineItemId=HI2PTRMVLNCZEXP, productId=online:en:US:d3k3245, quantity=2}" } }

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The API is expecting an Array of Google_Service_ShoppingContent_OrderShipmentLineItemShipment class.

```
$lineItemShipments = array();
$lineItemShipment = new Google_Service_ShoppingContent_OrderShipmentLineItemShipment();
$lineItemShipment->setLineItemId($item->getId());
$lineItemShipment->setQuantity($item->quantityPending);
$lineItemShipments[] = $lineItemShipment;
$postBody->setLineItems($lineItemShipments);
```